# My helmet had a bad fall. Is it still good?

Tags: helmets

I just stupidly dropped my helmet on the floor from a quite high distance. I know (or rather, heard of) that motorbike helmets must be inspected in such cases.

Is it the same for bike helmets? How can I tell if it is still safe?

Comment: How high is "quite high"?  Though the canonical advice is, of course, "replace it", I'd not be too worried about a helmet that dropped from 6 feet or so, so long as a reasonably close inspection reveals nothing.

Comment: I wonder if physical analysis of the energies involved can approximately be carried out. After all, a helmet has far less mass than a helmet + rider.

Comment: @Daniel it is indeed around 6 feet. A quick inspection revealed very small irregularities, small cracks in the foam, at the spot which I suspect hit the floor. For now I'm inclined to think that it is damaged, but it is true that it still looks new from the outside...

Comment: Motorcycle helmets have more mass so they would hit the floor with more force (but they are designed to absorb more force as well).  A fall will possibly crack the shell on them as well.  The shell is used to prevent punctures (source:  beginner riding course) so a crack could compromise that protection.  I would just inspect it, try pushing on the shell to see how far down it goes, and then ask "how do I feel about using it".

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[BHSI.org](http://bhsi.org/replace.htm) says the following:

**Did you drop it hard enough to crack the foam? Replace.**

> For starters, most people are aware that you must replace a helmet
>   after any crash where your head hit. The foam part of a helmet is made
>   for one-time use, and after crushing once it is no longer as
>   protective as it was, even if it still looks intact. Bear in mind that
>   if the helmet did its job most people would tell you that they did not
>   even hit their head, or did not hit their head that hard. And the thin
>   shells on most helmets now tend to hide any dents in the foam. But if
>   you can see marks on the shell or measure any foam crush at all,
>   replace the helmet. (Helmets made of EPP foam do recover, but there
>   are few EPP helmets on the market. Yours is EPS or EPU unless
>   otherwise labeled.)
>
> You can also crack the helmet foam or damage it by dropping the helmet
>   on a hard surface. The cracks may be small and hard to see, so you
>   need to look carefully. Cracks in the foam always require replacement
>   of the helmet.
>
> You may be reluctant to replace a helmet that looks almost as good as
>   new, but if you did hit, you don't want to take chances on where you
>   will hit next time. If the foam is cracked under the thin shell, it
>   will be more likely to fly apart in your next crash. Many
>   manufacturers will replace crashed helmets for a nominal fee, and most
>   will also inspect crashed helmets to see if they need replacement.
>   Call them if you are in doubt.

Comment: It seems to be slightly, very lightly cracked, but honestly this could even be a factory defect... The outer shell looks ok. Any idea of how smooth the foam surface should be?

Comment: At the same time I don't see any crack anywhere else, and this is the supposed impact zone...

Comment: @Antoine_935 - I very seriously doubt the crack you see is a factory defect.  Any cracks should have been caught by the factory's QA process and they would not sell the helmet.